# Galaxy Tab 3 GT-P5210 Downgrade to 4.0.3 ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, downgrade, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I was searching the web trying to find ROMs for downgrading my Galaxy Tab 3. No matter how deep I have gone, it seems that there is not any available ROM for Android 4.0.3 dedicated for my device. A little more searching gave me the feeling that this kind of ROM **will never be available** for downgrading.

Does anyone know if such a ROM exists, or if it is impossible to exist?

Comment: Have you checked forum.xda-developers.com ? If it's not there, you won't find anywhere...

Comment: oh yes I have checked it some thousand times...I think that I won't find it anywhere...unless I make a ROM of my own..

Comment: Isn't came with Android 4.2.2? `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_3_10.1` so that won't be there. Nobody gonna port old rom to the new phone. If you know codename, check download.cyanogenmod.com

Comment: I have checked already Cyanogenmod, AOKP, MIUI . Also sammobile and samsung-updates. Many times, in many days.
You are probably right, nobody is going to port an old rom to the new phone, especially for Tab3 which has an Intel Atom instead of an ARM processor. Even if I try to compile from source, I will still need some vendor components which are probably proprietary or unavailable.

Comment: Can you tell me why do you need ICS on yr tab 3? There may be some tweak that can be done on your JB?

Comment: I need to work on an application implemented for the old bluetooth stack. The application was developed for ICS. Unless google release an update on 4.4 KitKat that allows L2CAP communication, I will have to work on ICS.